# Django hostname middleware gets cached

Tags: django, caching, middleware

I created a Django project to manage two separate sites that share some backend code. Both of the sites are inside separate apps. Each app has its own models.py, views.py, templates etc...

To be able to react differently to different hostnames, I created an URLconf middleware:

```
class HostnameBasedUrlconfMiddleware(object):
    """This middleware parses the hostname from the request, and selects the
    urlconf accordingly.

    To set a custom urlconf according to the current hostname, add an URLCONF
    dictionary to your settings.py file.

    URLCONF = {
        'example.com': 'urls_example',
        'example.dev': 'urls_dev',
        'admin.example.dev': 'apps.admin.urls'
    }

    If the hostname is not found in the URLCONF dictionary, the default
    ROOT_URLCONF setting will be used.

    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        # Decide which urlconf to use. Fallback is to use the ROOT_URLCONF
        # as defined in the settings.py file.
        try:
            hostname = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
            request.urlconf = settings.URLCONF[hostname]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            pass

        return None
```

This seemed to work at first, but then I became aware that some kind of caching must be happening.

When starting the server and requesting site A, it would show up. If I then request site B, site A shows up. Sometimes (but not always), after several reloads, site B would finally show up. After restarting the server and requesting site B, it would show up, but now site A would show site B content.

This happened with the builtin devserver as well as with gunicorn.

I tried to request the site with curl to avoid browser caching, no difference.

I also suspected it could be some kind of template name collision, but all templates are inside a uniquely named subfolder inside their respective template folders.

I don't have memcached installed and I'm not using any caching middleware.

What could be the problem? Is there some internal automatic caching going on?

Comment: How are you serving your separate hostnames?

Comment: Currently via the hosts file. It will be switched to normal DNS as soon as it's in production. Both domains should be served via the same Django instance.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem and it's driving me nuts. I appreciate Jordan's response but it doesn't answer your question. If I had an answer to your question that would make my life a lot easier. :)

Comment: I'm going to create a bounty on this question to see if someone can give a better answer.

Comment: Just as I was writing out the info for the bounty I went back into my system to reproduce it a few more times to include additional details and now I can't reproduce it for the life of me. I'm thoroughly confused at the moment... If it starts happening again I'll be back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code in question that substitutes in the urlconf (for 1.3 at least):

**django.core.handlers.base**:

```
class BaseHandler(object):

   [...snip...]

   def get_response(self, request):
        "Returns an HttpResponse object for the given HttpRequest"
        from django.core import exceptions, urlresolvers
        from django.conf import settings

        try:
            # Setup default url resolver for this thread, this code is outside
            # the try/except so we don't get a spurious "unbound local
            # variable" exception in the event an exception is raised before
            # resolver is set
            urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
            urlresolvers.set_urlconf(urlconf)
            resolver = urlresolvers.RegexURLResolver(r'^/', urlconf)
            try:
                response = None
                # Apply request middleware
                for middleware_method in self._request_middleware:
                    response = middleware_method(request)
                    if response:
                        break

                if response is None:
                    if hasattr(request, "urlconf"):
                        # Reset url resolver with a custom urlconf.
                        urlconf = request.urlconf
                        urlresolvers.set_urlconf(urlconf)
                        resolver = urlresolvers.RegexURLResolver(r'^/', urlconf)
    [...snip...]
```

So, it looks like it's just using the value directly from `request.urlconf`. And your middleware is setting the `request` value directly.

I'd install [django-debug-toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar/0.8.4) to confirm whether or not the value for `request.urlconf` is a) being set or b) being changed along the way.

To make absolutely sure, why not change the code temporarily to something like:

```
            request.urlconf = settings.URLCONF[hostname]
            request.urlconf_set = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Then you can look at the values in the debug toolbar (or just output them in a template) to see what might be going on.

**However**, I would suggest instead of using middleware, that you simply set up different settings.py files for each domain. Then, in whatever web server you're using, set each one up to use its own .wsgi file, which points to its own settings file, like so:

**settings_a.py**:

```
from settings import *
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls_a.py'
```

**settings_b.py**

```
from settings import *
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls_b.py'
```

Comment: I already debugged the toolbar by outputting the current request.urlconf at the end of the middleware. I'm pretty sure the value gets set correctly. But I see that creating two different settings files would make sense. We're already using two settings files for dev and production, by abstracting the similarities into a common settings file it could work quite nicely.

Comment: Your post didn't really reveal/solve the problem, but the idea with separating the settings.py files helped. Thanks!